# How to upload and process csv file with nodejs and hapi@8.8.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js, import-csv

I started working with an existing project which is build with Hapi's older version (hapi@8.8.1) and node version is also older on server. And i got a task to upload CSV file which includes Email address of users and i need to process users data with the help of email provided in the CSV file.
**List of task is as follow:-**

- Task 1. Upload and save CSV on server inside a directory
  "root/uploaded_csv".
- Task 2. Read and process CSV data to search users in the database
  with the help of email mentioned in the CSV at Column 2.
- Task 3. Save imported CSV file on AWS s3 server.

As i am dealing with older node and hapi's versions and at that stage i can't even update all the versions and dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. Receive CSV as API parameter as follow

```
      payload: {
          maxBytes: 20715200,
          output: 'stream',
          parse: true,
          allow: 'multipart/form-data'
      },
```

Step 2. Validate imported CSV file as follow:

```
validate: {
importedCsv: Joi.any()
                    .meta({swaggerType: 'file'})
                    .required()
                    .allow('')
                    .description('CSV file')

          },
```

Step 3. To Upload and save CSV on server inside a directory "root/XXX".

```
csvFileName = ""+moment().utc().format('XXXX-XX-XX')+".csv";
          csvFilePath = Path.resolve(".") + "/XXX/" + csvFileName ;
          var file = fs.createWriteStream(csvFilePath);
          file.on('error', function (err) {
             console.log(err.message);
          });
          payload.importedCsv.pipe(file);
          payload.importedCsv.on('end', function (err) {
              if(err){
                cb(ERROR);
              }else{
                cb(null);
              }
          });
```

Step 4. To Read and process CSV data to search users in the database with the help of email mentioned in the CSV at Column 2.

```
var obj = csv();
obj.from.path(csvFilePath).to.array(function (data) {            
async.forEach(data, function (item, callback){
    /** Data processing and query part **/
    console.log(item[1]); /* will print email from the second cloumn in the CSV */
}, function(err) {    
      cb(null);
   });
});
```

Step 5. To save imported CSV file on AWS s3 server.

```
fs.readFile(csvFilePath, function (error, fileBuffer) {
            var accessKeyId = XXXXXX;
            var secretAccessKeyId = XXXXXX;
            AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: secretAccessKeyId});
            var s3bucket = new AWS.S3();
            var params = {
                Bucket: XXXXXXX,
                Key: 'XXX' + '/' + csvFileName,
                Body: fileBuffer,
                ACL: 'public-read',
                ContentType: payload.importedCsv.hapi.headers['content-type']
            };

            s3bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                  // cb(ERROR);
                }else{
                  // cb(null);
                }
            });
});
```